# Find out pixels of an image under a vector

Tags: graphics, vector, 2d, raster

This might be a simple problem but I can't manage to solve it.

I've got this heightmap which I need to process. I must allow the user to trace a vector over an image, indicating which "line" of the height map should be processed at a given time.

The question is, once I got the vector traced, how can I find out which pixels of the raster image lie "under" said vector?

It's easy if the vector is horizontal or vertical, or even if it draws a 45º angle, but not with an arbitrary rotation angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I'm following you, but are you perhaps looking for something like [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)?

Comment: That's SO it! Thanks, sometimes you have a problem but you don't know how's it called :P

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't know about that!